# How to update the fields of a table

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a table called `users_category` with fields: `ID and Name`:

```
 ID Name

 1 | Sports
 --------------
 2 | Movies
 --------------
 3 | Politics
```

I always make changes to fields. The following query adds new fields to the DB:

```
query = "INSERT INTO users_category (Id, Name) VALUES (%s, %s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
```

How do I update different fields without using it's ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can update fields based on their existing values. For example, this will change the `Name` of any `users_category` that is currently `Movies` into `Films`:

`query = "UPDATE users_category SET Name = 'Films' WHERE Name = 'Movies'"`

If your data looks like this:

```
 ID Name

 1 | Sports
 --------------
 2 | Movies
 --------------
 3 | Politics
 --------------
 4 | Movies
```

then both lines with `Name` of `Movies` will be updated.

If you want to be sure of only changing the one record that corresponds to a particular `ID`, you will need to use the `ID` in the query:

`query = "UPDATE users_category SET Name = 'Films' WHERE ID = 2"`

That's the only way we can get a table like this:

```
 ID Name

 1 | Sports
 --------------
 2 | Films
 --------------
 3 | Politics
 --------------
 4 | Movies
```